# Creating a QScrollBar with a HorizontalLayout inside with Buttons

Tags: qt, layout, button, scrollbar

I am stuck with a problem in QT. I want my software to have a top bar, with all the software available in a specific folder. So for each item in the folder I add a button with the name of that folder. For that i was thinking of a bar without scroll when the buttons do not reach the limit of the app height, but when they reach that value, a scroll bar appears.

The problem is that i don't find any way (using design) to do so... I found a simple way to do that with coding, but I cannot use HorizontalLayout :S...)

Thanks in advance for all help.

Best Regards,
Luis Da Costa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a custom widget which contains an item view derived from [QAbstractItemView](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qabstractitemview.html). Then you can have your own buttons which you can show when you need them. QAbstractItemView has the scroll functionalities you will need. By implementing your own delegates you can define the look of your items.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I'm having problems implementing that :S can you give me a example (code) please ?